# if/else statement referring to alpha of a UIbutton is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, alpha

this will be difficult without pasting my whole code, but I am hoping I'm missing something simple. Basically, when there is a web link (coming from an NSDictionary), I would like to show a UIbutton, when there isn't, the button should be invisible.

First of all  I set the UIButton to invisible in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

thereafter is a method `- (void)animationDidEndOnAnswer` where the button should appear if there is a link. If I just put `button.alpha = 1;` then it displays at the correct time, but what I'm trying to do is have it not display if there is no weblink.

Here is the code I currently have in that method:

```
  - (void)animationDidEndOnAnswer 
    { 
          if ([[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"] == @"") {
               leesmeerButton.alpha = 0;
          } 

          else {
             leesmeerButton.alpha = 1;
          }

    NSLog(@"link is %@", [[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"]);

}
```

In the log, when there is no link I see nothing (not even a space). When there is, I see the proper weblink... I've also tried `if ([[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"] == nil)` but that also didn't work.

Any help is appreciated! thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using `==` on an `NSString`? You should be using `-isEqual:` or `-isEqualToString:`. Or in this particular case, to handle both `@""` and `nil`, you should just ask for the `-length` and compare to 0.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'm using == because I'm new to this! Your solution works nicely, thank you! I will keep that in mind of the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on this line

```
if ([[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"] == @"")
```

instead of that use

```
if ([[[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"] isEqualToString:@""] || [[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"] != nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `alpha` you should use `hidden` property. Just like that:

```
      if ([[[questions questionOnScreen] objectForKey:@"link"]isEqualToString:@""])
           leesmeerButton.hidden = YES;
      else
           leesmeerButton.hidden = NO;
```

Or switch the YES and NO.

Hope it helps